# Iterating through row range group data and take an action

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting to know Excel VBA. I have a working program that uses an action button on one sheet opens a source workbook and data worksheet, selects data and puts that into a second workbook and destination sheet. I then sort the data as needed and it looks like this
[Destination sheet, sorted and annotated duplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Goo1W.png)

I am now trying to select the data based on col 2 "B" where the items are duplicated and/or not duplicated then perform an action (send an email to the manager about the staff under their control). I can get an email to work but its selecting the data that I'm having trouble with.

the output data would be col 1 & col 3 to 5 e.g.

---

Dear Manager1,

you staff member/s listed below have achieved  xyz

1. Person1   22/06/2017  11/08/2017  22/08/2017
2. Person11  22/06/2017  11/08/2017  22/08/2017
3. Person15  22/06/2017  11/08/2017  22/08/2017

congratulations....

---

So what I hope somebody can help me with is a clue how I get to look at the data in col 2
add the Row data required to an array or something then to check the next Row add it to the same something until it is different to the next Row 
Pause do the action then do the next iteration.  Resulting in:

- Manager1 .....Person 1,11,15

  #### action
- Manager10 ..... Person 10

  #### action
- Manager2 ..... Person 12,16,2,25,28

  #### action
- Manager3 ..... Person 13,17,26,29,3

  #### action

until last line is reached.

I am so confused with arrays / lookups and loops I have lost the plot somewhere along the way.
I have a variable **lastTmp** which tells me the last line of data in the set, this will vary each month.
The Range is:
`Set rng1 = Range("B5:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row)`
The last piece of my working code is:

```
Dim lp As Integer
lp = 1
For Each cell In rng1
    If 1 < Application.CountIf(rng1, cell.Value) Then
        With cell
                .Offset(0, 4) = "duplicate : "
                .Offset(0, 5) = lp
                End With
                Else
                With cell
                .Offset(0, 4) = "NOT duplicate : "
                .Offset(0, 5) = 0
                End With
        End If
    Next cell
```

Comment: I am not sure what exactly your question is. Can you formulate the exact step you need help with in one sentence?

Answer (score 0):

You will be better placed to confront confusion if you do your indenting more logically. Related `For / Next`, `If / Else / End If` and `With / End With` should always be on the same indent level for easier reading. I rearranged your original code like this:-

```
For Each Cell In Rng1
    If 1 < Application.CountIf(Rng1, Cell.Value) Then
        With Cell
            .Offset(0, 4) = "duplicate : "
            .Offset(0, 5) = lp
        End With
    Else
        With Cell
            .Offset(0, 4) = "NOT duplicate : "
            .Offset(0, 5) = 0
        End With
    End If
Next Cell
```

It now becomes apparent that the `With Cell / End With` need not be duplicated. I have further presumed that your variable `lp` actually was intended to hold the count. That made me arrive at the following compression of your code.

```
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim lp As Integer

' the sheet isn't specified: uses the ActiveSheet
Set Rng1 = Range("B5:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

For Each Cell In Rng1
    With Cell
        lp = Application.CountIf(Rng1, .Value)
        .Offset(0, 4) = IIf(lp, "", "NOT ") & "duplicate : "
        .Offset(0, 5) = lp
    End With
Next Cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a Dictionary or Collection, whenever, checking for duplicates.

Here I use a Dictionary of Dictionaries to compile lists of Persons by Manager.

[image: Output]

```
Sub ListManagerList1()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim manager As String, person As String
    Dim key As Variant

    Dim dictManagers As Object
    Set dictManagers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each cell In Range("B5:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        manager = cell.Value
        person = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

        If Not dictManagers.Exists(manager) Then
            dictManagers.Add manager, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        End If

        If Not dictManagers(manager).Exists(person) Then
            dictManagers(manager).Add person, vbNullString
        End If
    Next

    For Each key In dictManagers
        Debug.Print key & " -> "; Join(dictManagers(key).Keys(), ",")
    Next

End Sub
```

I recommend you wanting [Excel VBA Introduction Part 39 - Dictionaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dND4coLI_B8&t=420s&index=43&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is as in the image

[image]

Then following code will give you result as in the image below.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, destSht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim arr1(), arr2()
    Dim dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")  'change Sheet2 to your data sheet
    Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'change Sheet1 to your output sheet

    arr1 = Application.Index(srcSht.Cells, [row(1:7000)], Array(2, 1))  'See note below
    arr2 = arr1

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr1, 1)
        If Not dict.exists(LCase$(arr1(i, 1))) Then
            dict.Add LCase$(arr1(i, 1)), i
        Else
            arr2(i, 1) = vbNullString
            arr2(dict.Item(LCase$(arr1(i, 1))), 2) = arr2(dict.Item(LCase$(arr1(i, 1))), 2) & "," & arr1(i, 2)
        End If
    Next
    destSht.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr1, 1), UBound(arr1, 2)) = arr2 'display result
    destSht.Columns("a").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

[image]

***Note :*** For details on assigning range to array see [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/564473-transfer-multiple-ranges-one-array.html).